# Extention of file being dropped during AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this script , trying to delete an image with AJAX call.

**PHP**

```
 foreach ( $in_folder as $img => $v ) {

    echo '
        <span class="imageHolder">
         <a onclick="DeleteImage('.$img.'); return false;" href="javascript:;">X</a>
         <img src="uploads/' . $img .'"/>
            <span class="uploaded">
            </span>
        </span>';
    // print_r($in_folder);
    }
```

**The JS :**

```
 function DeleteImage(img){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'delete.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: img,
            success: function(datos){
                console.log("check");
            }
        });
    }
```

**delete.php**

```
 if($_GET["action"]=="deleteimage")
    {
        $imagefile = $POST['img'];
        $img_path = 'uploads/' . $img;
        unlink ( $img_path ); 
    }
```

The problem is the JS part , I am getting an error :

```
Error: ReferenceError: IMAGE_NAME is not defined
Source File: http://localhost/dev/_upload_test/
Line: 1
```

However ,the PHP `$img` variable is outputting `IMAGE_NAME.jpg`

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="DeleteImage(IMAGE_NAME.jpg); return false;">X</a>
```

Shouldn´t that error be

```
Error: ReferenceError: IMAGE_NAME.jpg is not defined
```

( where is the extention ?? )

Obviously my extention `.jpg` is being cut off by the ajax process , But since `my JS skills are <= 0` , I am having trouble understanding what is getting wrong in the process  ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change

```
data: img,
```

to

```
data: { img:img },
```

or use

```
data: "img="+img,
```

Also you need to wrap string using `'` or `"` .

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="DeleteImage('IMAGE_NAME.jpg'); return false;">X</a>
<!--                                      --^--          --^--                  -->
```

Change your php code to like this,

```
foreach ( $in_folder as $img => $v ) {
echo '
        <span class="imageHolder">
         <a onclick="DeleteImage(\''.$img.'\'); return false;" href="javascript:;">X</a>
         <img src="uploads/' . $img .'"/>
            <span class="uploaded">
            </span>
        </span>';
    // print_r($in_folder);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks , changing the `data:...` is not helping for that specific error ( although probably correct )  , but the brackets might . My original line is `<a href="javascript:;" onclick="DeleteImage(" ' .$img . ' "); return false;\">X</a>` - but any escape attempt gives me a syntax error , or illegal character..

Comment: `echo '
        <span class="imageHolder">
         <a onclick="DeleteImage(\''.$img.'\'); return false;" href="javascript:;">X</a>
         <img src="uploads/' . $img .'"/>
            <span class="uploaded">
            </span>
        </span>';
    // print_r($in_folder);
    }`

Comment: Thanks, error gonenow ( I always have trouble escaping ) now I need to change the delete.php - or paths . becasue it is doing nothing :-)

Answer (score 1):

Reason for your reference error "IMAGE_NAME is not defined" would be that in the following line, there are no quotes around the file name.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="DeleteImage(IMAGE_NAME.jpg); return false;">X</a>
```

Javascript then expects your IMAGE_NAME to be an object, and tries to call the jpg property of the undefined object. That's where your ".jpg" 'disappears'.

The php code would then be:

```
foreach ( $in_folder as $img => $v ) {
    echo '
        <span class="imageHolder">
         <a onclick="DeleteImage('."'".$img."'".'); return false;" href="javascript:;">X</a>
         <img src="uploads/' . $img .'"/>
            <span class="uploaded">
            </span>
        </span>';
    // print_r($in_folder);
}
```

Note the "'" (double quote, single quote, double quote) I've added around $img inside the DeleteImage function.

Hope this helps you!

Edit: This changes the delete link to:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="DeleteImage('IMAGE_NAME.jpg'); return false;">X</a>
```

Comment: ok, error is gone . :-) but doing nothing . I better check my delete.php as well..

Comment: you could try a non-destructive test first (try file_exists before unlink) and see if the file can be found.

Comment: also, you don't have $_GET['action'] if you post to delete.php ;-)

Comment: trouble was `$img_path = 'uploads/' . $img;` , should be `$img_path = 'uploads/' . $imagefile;`

Comment: yes ofcourse, lol. did you check if you get that $_GET['action']?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49881/discussion-between-obmerk-kronen-and-joucke-hempenius)

Comment: There appears to be no posting , I tried `file_put_contents('log.txt', $imagefile.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);` and there is nothing .. so I assume the `POST` action is mute ..